# animating the virtual keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I made my app detect the orientation on the iPad and readjust it's location position accordingly fine so it works good on portrait and landscape.

my problem in the virtual keyboard method that i have it's not considering the orientation: in portrait once user tap one of the text boxes the method would lift up the view to make room for the keyboard and have the text box visible (not covered) -  However when user in landscape and tap a text box the animation would push the view sideways instead of up, as if it's still in portrait.  (same if i hold the iPad upside-down it will push my view frame down instead of up)

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    CGRect textFieldRect = [self.view.window convertRect:textField.bounds fromView:textField];

    CGRect viewRect = [self.view.window convertRect:self.view.bounds fromView:self.view];
    CGFloat midline = textFieldRect.origin.y + 0.5 * textFieldRect.size.height;
    CGFloat numerator = midline - viewRect.origin.y - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION * viewRect.size.height;
    CGFloat denominator = (MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION) * viewRect.size.height;
    CGFloat heightFraction = numerator / denominator;
    if (heightFraction < 0.0)  {
        heightFraction = 0.0;
    }
    else if (heightFraction > 1.0)   {
        heightFraction = 1.0;
    }

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation =[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
        orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)   {
        animatedDistance = floor(PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
    }
    else    {
        animatedDistance = floor(LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
    }

    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y -= animatedDistance;
    // viewFrame.origin.x -= animatedDistance;


    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];
    [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

I also have:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

How should i change the method to animate it correctly when the device changes orientation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detect the orientation and decide which direction to move the view in based on that info.

```
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation==UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    viewFrame.origin.x -= animatedDistance;
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation==UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    viewFrame.origin.x += animatedDistance;
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation==UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)
    viewFrame.origin.y -= animatedDistance;
if ([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation==UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    viewFrame.origin.y += animatedDistance;
```

Comment: inside the code i have viewFrame.origin.y -= animatedDistance;  so it should lift up the view as it does ok when i'm in portrait but in landscape the up is sideways if you see what i mean (origin.y behave like it is origin sideway) ,i'm not sure what am i missing

Comment: works like a charm. (For information sake i had to reverse the move once the text box was resigned.) Thanks man.